# Can the post-increment operator be used in the parameters of a function call? in C?

Tags: c, function, post-increment

My question pertains to function calls in general, but I thought of it
while I was writing a priority queue using a heap. Just to give some context (not that it matters much) my heap stores items top to bottom left to right and I represent the heap as an array of structures. Upon inserting a new item, I just put it in the last place in the heap and then call the function "fix_up" at the bottom which will move the item to the proper place in the heap. I am wondering if instead of doing...

```
fix_up(pQueue->heap, pQueue->size);
pQueue->size++;
```

...I could just do...

```
fix_up(pQueue->heap, pQueue->size++);
```

I am unsure as to if this is ok for a few reasons.
1) Since pQueue->size is in the function call, I'm not even sure if it's actually pQueue->size or rather a copy of the integer stored in pQueue->size. If it was a copy then obviously I wouldn't be adding 1 to the actual pQueue->size so there'd be no point in doing this.

2) Since it's a function call, it is going to then go into the function fix_up and execute all the code there. I am wondering if this would have an unintended consequence of maybe when it went to fix_up it would get incremented by 1 and my index would be 1 higher than I intended while executing fix_up? Or would it do what it's supposed to do and wait until after fix_up had finished executing?

3) Even if it is ok, is it considered a good coding practice for C?

```
Status priority_queue_insert(PRIORITY_QUEUE hQueue, int priority_level, int data_item)
{
    Priority_queue *pQueue = (Priority_queue*)hQueue;
    Item *temp_heap;
    int i;

    /*Resize if necessary*/
    if (pQueue->size >= pQueue->capacity) {
        temp_heap = (Item*)malloc(sizeof(Item) * pQueue->capacity * 2);
        if (temp_heap == NULL)
            return FAILURE;
        for (i = 0; i < pQueue->size; i++)
            temp_heap[i] = pQueue->heap[i];
        pQueue->capacity *= 2;
    }

    /*Either resizing was not necessary or it successfully resized*/
    pQueue->heap[pQueue->size].key = priority_level;
    pQueue->heap[pQueue->size].data = data_item;

    /*Now it is placed as the last item in the heap. Fixup as necessary*/
    fix_up(pQueue->heap, pQueue->size);
    pQueue->size++;

    //continue writing function code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use it directly in the expression you pass as argument.

A statement like

```
fix_up(pQueue->heap, pQueue->size++);
```

is somewhat equivalent to

```
{
    int old_value = pQueue->size;
    pQueue->size = pQueue->size + 1;
    fix_up(pQueue->heap, old_value);
}
```

---

A note about the "equivalent" example above. Since the order of evaluation of arguments to function calls is not specified, the actual increment of `pQueue->size` could happen *after* the call to `fix_up`. And it also means that using `pQueue->size` more than once in the same call would lead to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

However, you cannot do this:

```
foo(myStruct->size++, myStruct->size)
```

The reason is that the C standard does not say in which order the arguments should be evaluated. This would lead to undefined behavior.

> 1) Since pQueue->size is in the function call, I'm not even sure if it's actually pQueue->size or rather a copy of the integer stored in pQueue->size. If it was a copy then obviously I wouldn't be adding 1 to the actual pQueue->size so there'd be no point in doing this.

Whatever argument you're sending to a function, it will be evaluated before the function starts to execute. So

```
T var = expr;
foo(var);
```

is always equivalent to

```
foo(expr);
```

> 2) Since it's a function call, it is going to then go into the function fix_up and execute all the code there. I am wondering if this would have an unintended consequence of maybe when it went to fix_up it would get incremented by 1 and my index would be 1 higher than I intended while executing fix_up? Or would it do what it's supposed to do and wait until after fix_up had finished executing?

See above

> 3) Even if it is ok, is it considered a good coding practice for C?

Somewhat subjective, and a bit OT for this site, but I'll answer it anyway from my personal view. In general, I would try to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

Though, the other posts already answer this question, but none of them talk about role of [Sequence Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point), in this particular case, which can greatly help in clarifying OP's doubt.

From [**this**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order) *[emphasis mine]*:

> There is a sequence point after the evaluation of all function arguments and of the function designator, and **before the actual function call**.

From [**this**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_incdec) *[emphasis mine]*:

> Increment operators initiate the side-effect of adding the value 1 of appropriate type to the operand. Decrement operators initiate the side-effect of subtracting the value 1 of appropriate type from the operand. As with any other side-effects, these operations **complete at or before the next sequence point**.

Also, the post increment operator increase the value of operand by 1 **but the value of the expression is the operand's original value prior to the increment operation.**

So, in this statement:

```
fix_up(pQueue->heap, pQueue->size++);
```

the value of `pQueue->size` will be increased by `1` before the `fix_up()` function call but the argument value will be the original value prior to the increment operation.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can use it in function calls, but please note that your two examples are *not* equivalent. The `pQueue->heap` argument may be evaluated before or after `pQueue->size++` and you can't know or rely on the order. Consider this example :

```
int func (void)
{
  static int x = 0;
  x++;
  return x;
}

printf("%d %d", func(), func());
```

This will print `1 2` or `2 1` and we can't know which we'll get. The compiler need not evalute the function parameters consistently throughout the program. So if we add a second `printf("%d %d", func(), func());` we could get something like `1 2 4 3` as output.

The importance here is to not write code which relies on order of evaluation. Which is the same reason as mixing ++ with other operations or side-effects in the same expression is bad practice. It can even lead to undefined behavior in some cases.

To answer your questions:

> 1) Since pQueue->size is in the function call, I'm not even sure if it's actually pQueue->size or rather a copy of the integer stored in pQueue->size. If it was a copy then obviously I wouldn't be adding 1 to the actual pQueue->size so there'd be no point in doing this.

The ++ is applied to the variable in the caller, so this isn't an issue. The local copy of the variable happens during function call, independently of the ++. However, the result of a ++ operation is not a so-called "lvalue" (addressable data), so this code is not valid:

```
void func (int* a);
...
func(&x++);
```

++ takes precedence and is evaluted first. The result is not an lvalue and cannot have its address taken.

---

> 2) Since it's a function call, it is going to then go into the function fix_up and execute all the code there. I am wondering if this would have an unintended consequence of maybe when it went to fix_up it would get incremented by 1 and my index would be 1 higher than I intended while executing fix_up? Or would it do what it's supposed to do and wait until after fix_up had finished executing?

This isn't an issue unless the function modifies the original variable through a global pointer or such. In that case you would have problems. For example

```
int* ptr;

void func (int a)
{
  *ptr = 1;
}

int x=5;
ptr = &x;
func(x++);
```

This is very questionable code and `x` will be 1 after the line `func(x++);` and not 6 as one might have expected. This is because the function call expression is evaluated and finished before the function call.

---

> 3) Even if it is ok, is it considered a good coding practice for C?

It will work ok in your case but it is bad practice. Specifically, mixing the `++` or `--` operators together with other operators in the same expression is bad (although common) practice, since it has a high potential for bugs and tends to make code less readable.

Your original code with `pQueue->size++;` on a line of it's own is superior in every way - stick with that. Contrary to popular belief, when writing C, you get no bonus points for "most operators on a single line". You may however get bugs and maintenance problems.